# jQuery TouchSwipe horizontal scrolling keeps going to start

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, touch, swipe

I'm using jQuery TouchSwipe to make some horizontal, scrollable divs on a mobile site. I've got it set up so that the div scrolls left or right, depending on how you swipe. My problem lies within after you stop swiping and go to swipe again. When you go to swipe, the div goes back to the beginning. Obviously I want the div to stay where it's at and scroll from that position. Here is what I have so far.

```
$('#table_set').swipe({
  swipeStatus:swipe1, allowPageScroll:'horizontal'
});
function swipe1(event, phase, direction, distance, duration){
  if(direction == 'left'{
    $(this).scrollLeft(distance);
  }else{
    $(this).scrollLeft('-' + distance);
  }
}
```

I understand why it's going to the beginning of the div. Every time that you touch, `duration` equals 0. I just don't know what the next steps are. Any help would be amazing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've created a demo of the swiping. I think the issue with going to the beginning of the div was because direction returns `null` if there was just a click and no swiping.

I've avoided this by exiting the callback if direction is `null`.

I'm not sure why you need the swiping at all because the scrolling works with-out touchSwipe.

Please finde the demo below and here at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/pskbggmt/).

```js
var IMAGECOUNT = 10;
var url = 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200';
var imgArr = [];
var loadCounter = 10;

var decCounter = function(){
    loadCounter--;
    if (!loadCounter) $("#table_set").trigger('allImgLoaded');
};

$(function() {
    var $table = $('#table_set');
    var img;
    //init table set with dummy images
    for(var i=0; i< IMAGECOUNT; i++){
        imgArr[i] = new Image();
        imgArr[i].src = url + '?' + (new Date()).getTime(); // add time to avoid caching
        imgArr[i].onload = decCounter;
    }
    
    $("#table_set").on('allImgLoaded', function() {
        //console.log(imgArr);
        $table.append(imgArr);
    });
});


$('#table_set').swipe({
  swipeStatus:swipe1, allowPageScroll:'horizontal'
});
function swipe1(event, phase, direction, distance, duration){
    console.log('swiped!', direction, distance, duration);
    if ( direction === null ) return; // no swipe
    
    var curPos = $(this).scrollLeft();
    var newPos = curPos;
  if(direction == 'left'){
      newPos += distance;
    $(this).scrollLeft(newPos);
  }else{
      newPos -= distance;
    $(this).scrollLeft(newPos);
  }
}
```

```css
#table_set  {
    height: 210px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.touchswipe/1.6.4/jquery.touchSwipe.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table_set">
    
</div>
```